# Send same Email to extra recipient as the admin received

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce

On adding extra recipient on woocommerce order, the recipient generally receives the mail same as the customer receives.But i want to send extra recipient the mail what an admin receives.

**Below is my working code which receives email in customer format**

```
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_processing_order',
    'shop_email_recipient_filter_function',
    10,
    2
);
add_filter(
    'woocommerce_email_recipient_customer_completed_order',
    'shop_email_recipient_filter_function',
    10,
    2
);

function shop_email_recipient_filter_function($recipient, $order) {
    $shop = get_post_meta( $order->id, '_restaurant_id', true );
    $shop_owner_email = get_the_author_meta(
        'user_email',
        get_post_field('post_author', $shop)
    );
    $recipient .= ', ' . $shop_owner_email;
    return $recipient;
}
```

i want to send admin mail format